# matlplotlib figure throws TypeError from QT

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

## The problem

When I run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1203, in subplots
    fig = figure(**fig_kw)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 46, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, thisFig)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 53, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 76, in __init__
    FigureCanvasQT.__init__(self, figure)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py", line 66, in __init__
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'figure'
```

This worked until recently. I am not aware that I changed anything in the installed anaconda libraries, which are currently (only showing relevant libraries):

```
matplotlib                2.0.0               np111py35_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.6.2                         3    defaults
qtconsole                 4.2.1                    py35_1    defaults
```

What do I have to do to solve this?

## More information

When `import matplotlib` I get

```
Backend Qt4Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'qt4'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_console_utils.py", line 563, in do_enable_gui
    enable_gui(guiname)
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 528, in enable_gui
    return gui_hook(app)
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 195, in enable_qt4
    from pydev_ipython.inputhookqt4 import create_inputhook_qt4
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhookqt4.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pydev_ipython.qt_for_kernel import QtCore, QtGui
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/qt_for_kernel.py", line 85, in <module>
    QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QT_API = load_qt(api_opts)
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/qt_loaders.py", line 281, in load_qt
    api_options))
ImportError: 
    Could not load requested Qt binding. Please ensure that
    PyQt4 >= 4.7 or PySide >= 1.0.3 is available,
    and only one is imported per session.
    Currently-imported Qt library:   None
    PyQt4 installed:                 False
    PyQt5 installed:                 True
    PySide >= 1.0.3 installed:       True
    Tried to load:                   ['pyqtdefault']
```

When I run my script with `python script.py` I don't geht the above message, instead I get

```
[...]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1401: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

Comment: Since I'm not sure why the error is in *_qt4*, while you have qt5: Could it be that you unintentinally run this in a different version of python, which is also installed? You could also try to use `QT5Agg` backend, `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("QT5Agg")`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Now I am able to run `plt.figure`, but I get the message I added in the question. I feel this might be unhealthy... what to say about this?

Comment: What does "now" mean? In which environement are you running this? Is it a newly started python kernel, or could there be some old imports hanging around?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: "now" = after I did what you told me to. Before I did not load matplotlib with `import matplotlib`. It's a newly started kernel.

Comment: So, basically you're saying that `matplotlib.use("QT5Agg")` is completely ignored? Is the problem present when you run the script in a console `$> python script.py` ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I added what happens then.

Comment: What is the content of `script.py` in this case?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I think I found it: One of my own imported script had inside `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('TkAgg'); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I changed this to `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('QT5Agg'); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and now I don't get the above message anymore. Can you explain what happened?

Comment: This is what happens if you don't provide the code you are actually running in the question. See [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Sorry for this. This happened, because I am importing my own scripts and one of those had different settings. I cannot post everything, because I have a lot of code. I did not know what the sensitive part was. I learned from the incident though - hopefully I'll do better next time.

Comment: The problem was simply that the information you provided was incorrect. You said you run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])` however in reality you run something completely different.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: My bad. I tried this first and later went on to try what you said on my project. I forgot to get that straight. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that something like the following happened, although I cannot be certain because no exact code is given for the two cases in question.

The first error probably came up when you (undeliberately) tried to use a backend which is not installed.

```
import matplotlib #everthing works fine, no backend selected yet
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") #backend selected, would still be fine even if Tk wasnt installed.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # backend registered. Still not used.
plt.plot(..)  # now the backend will be used. Clash! 
              # Backend cannot be used, since underlying library is missing
```

Later on you tried to use a different backend.

```
import matplotlib #everthing works fine, no backend selected yet
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") #backend selected, would still be fine even if Tk wasnt installed.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # backend registered. Still not used.
....
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg") # backend "TkAgg" has already been registered. 
                         # You cannot change it anymore.
```

And this is what got you

> This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
>   because the backend has already been chosen;
>   matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
>   or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

#### Solution:

Always stick to this order if you need to use a specific backend.

1. `import matplotlib`
2. `matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`
3. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
4. Plotting , e.g. `plt.plot(..)`

If you don't need a specific backend, which should be the case most of the time, let matplotlib decide which one to choose - **omitt step 1 & 2!**. Especially when sharing code you cannot even be sure that the library for the required backend is installed on the other user's system.